# How can I add a 2-factor authentication to my shiny app connecting with googleauthr

Tags: shiny, google-api, google-oauth, google-plus, google-authentication

I have a shiny app that is authenticated thanks to google + API with the googleAuthR library. So When people click on the button they are redirected to the google authentication page. What I would like is to add the two factor authentication set up by google to this page like on the screenshot I provide. Could Someone help me ? Thanks [image]

Comment: What dit you try so far? Does this help: https://gist.github.com/hadley/144c406871768d0cbe66b0b810160528 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems that if you have enforced the two factor authentication on your google account then google handles it on its own. So when I logged on another computer it asked me to give a code I received by message. So the 2-factor auth seems to be linked to the google account.